# Replacing text of input field moves its location

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a search form that is controlled by some events, when it is blurred, the function checks to see if the value is blank, if it is, it puts the default search text back in place.

Here is a link to a sample page:
http://merkd.com/community

Here is the relevant function:

```
// searchInput is a jQuery reference to the <input> field
// searchTextColor is the original font color of the unfocused form
// searchText is the original search text
$('#header form').on('blur', 'input', function() {
    searchInput.css('color', searchTextColor);

    // When I comment these lines out, it doesn't move
    if ( searchInput.val() == '' ) {
        searchInput.val(searchText);
    }

});
```

To see the glitch, type some text into the search field, then delete it and blur the search form, the input field will move to the left.

Any idea why this would be happening? Like I said, if I don't change the text then it doesn't move. I don't know how this would be affecting the position of the element within the page.

Comment: there is a problem with the submit button in the form....

Comment: Chnage `var searchInput = $('#header form input');` to `var searchInput = $('#header form input[name="search"]');` You are setting values to both the input fields hence the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

this is happen that's why the problem is occur

see in firebug

```
   <input type="text" value="Search Teams, Players, Etc." name="search">
    <img title="Search" alt="Search" src="/engine/themes/img/search.white.focus.png">
    <input type="submit" value="Search Teams, Players, Etc.">
```

**solution**

```
    $('#header form').on('blur', 'input[name=search]', function() {// not use input other wise valuse also set in submit input box
        searchInput.css('color', searchTextColor);

        // When I comment these lines out, it doesn't move
        if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
            $(this).val(searchText);
        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a CSS animation effect to the input and now when the page loads it expands but the width attribute isn't changing. Do you know what's causing that or should I start a new question?

Comment: new question will better so anyone who face like this problem also get helped